# javascript object property assignment between different objects

Tags: javascript, properties

I read a snippet and confusing and could not find the rules or principle to explain that,the output is `Malibu`,why not `London`,the `adress: sherlock.address` in `let john = { surname: 'Watson', address: sherlock.address };` is to assign the value of`sherlock.adress` to `john.address`,but not overwrite `sherlock.adress`with`john.address`.How could I fiddle my hair.

```
let sherlock = {
  surname: 'Holmes',
  address: { city: 'London' } 
};
let john = {
  surname: 'Watson',
  address: sherlock.address
};
john.surname = 'Lennon';
john.address.city = 'Malibu';
console.log(sherlock.address.city); //
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: john.address and sherlock.address are _the same object_.

Comment: Yeah, both are pointing to same object

Comment: What are you expecting from the `console`. It is what it should be `malibu`

Comment: @Pointy,the output is Malibu,why not London?

Comment: @jonsharpe:`
let a=1
let b=a
b=5
console.log(a)`the output is `1` not '5' even a and b is the same variable,why?

Comment: Why would be `London`, Since both are same object.

Comment: `john.address` and `sherlock.address` are references to the same object, so mutating one - as you do here by updating the `city` property - necessarily updates the other. You would have to do `john.address = { ...sherlock.address, city: 'Malibu' };` to get a new object based on the other one.

Comment: @decpk: let a=1 let b=a b=5 console.log(a)the output is 1` not '5' even a and b is the same variable,why?

Comment: Numbers are primitive values, objects are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The confusing thing about objects is that PRIMITIVES behave differently to OBJECTS

When you "read"  a primitive string (or number or Boolean), such as `sherlock.surname`, you are taking the *value* of it, i.e. you are receiving a *copy* of the original data. So if you do

```
eureka = {surname: sherlock.surname}
```

then you can think of `eureka` receiving a "photocopy" of the original "Holmes". There will be two strings "Holmes" stored in your computer. You can change one, and the other will not change, because they are separate.

But when you "read" an *object*, such as `sherlock`, you should imagine that you are taking only *a pointer to the original object*. Not a copy of it, but another path through the computer to reach the same memory location. So if you do

```
eureka = sherlock
```

then this statement does *not* create a second copy of the string "Holmes" inside the computer. There is only one "Holmes" string in the memory of the computer. It is inside an object like this: `{surname: "Holmes"}`. `sherlock` points to that object, and `eureka` points to the same object. Therefore, when you edit some property of `eureka` or `sherlock`, the corresponding properties of both variables will have changed simultaneously. The two variable names, `eureka` and `sherlock`, are pointing to the same object in memory.

The above is quite elementary (excuse my pun!) but where it gets tricky is when you are referencing an object-within-an-object, or a primitive-within-an-object. Looking at the assignment statement alone *you cannot tell* whether the thing you are reading is a primitive or an object. You must know the structure in order to know.

```js
let a={b:{c:1}}

let w = a // This makes "w" an alias for the same single object, to which "a" also points

w.b.c=2
console.log(a)
// {
//  "b": {
//    "c": 2
//  }
// }

w.b = 3
console.log(a)
// {
//  "b": 3
// }
```

#### Annotating your script here

```js
let sherlock = {
  surname: 'Holmes',
  address: { city: 'London' } 
};
let john = {
  surname: 'Watson',
  address: sherlock.address // Here, you are not COPYING the { city: 'London'}, you are pointing at the same object in memory, i.e. the "address" property of sherlock.
};

john.surname = 'Lennon';
john.address.city = 'Malibu'; // When you go to john.address, you are now pointing into the piece of memory that sherlock is also using to store his address, so when you put a value into 'city', that will show up whether you access it as john.address or sherlock.address

console.log(sherlock.address.city);
```